# How to shift a video on a beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, media9

I have a video in my beamer presentation which is already in fullscreen size but is  shifted a few cm down and a few cm to the right. How can I shift an `\includemedia`  environment?

MMW :

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{default}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% absolute positioning of typeset material    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[4][center]{%
    % [#1]: box anchor: center (default) | 
    %                 south west | west | north west | north |
    %                 north east | east | south east | south | 
    %                 mid west | mid | mid east |
    %                 base west | base | base east 
    % #2: horizontal position (fraction of page width)
    % #3: vertical position (fraction of page height)
    % #4: content
    %
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,x=\paperwidth,y=\paperheight]{%
        \node[anchor=#1,inner sep=0pt]
        at ($(current page.south west)+(#2,#3)$) {#4};
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\title{some title}
\date{01.01.2010}
\subtitle{some subtitle}
\author{some authors}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hspace{-4pt}
\vspace{-10pt}
\centering
\includemedia[
width=\paperwidth,
height=\paperheight,
%keepaspectratio,
activate=pageopen,
passcontext,  %show VPlayer's right-click menu
addresource=camp-tschechien.mp4,
flashvars={
    source=camp-tschechien.mp4&autoPlay=true
}
]{}{VPlayer.swf} \hfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To force the video to be displayed on the whole frame just define a textbox which is placed in the center of the frame and include the video with the settings below.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{default}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% absolute positioning of typeset material    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[4][center]{%
    % [#1]: box anchor: center (default) | 
    %                 south west | west | north west | north |
    %                 north east | east | south east | south | 
    %                 mid west | mid | mid east |
    %                 base west | base | base east 
    % #2: horizontal position (fraction of page width)
    % #3: vertical position (fraction of page height)
    % #4: content
    %
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,x=\paperwidth,y=\paperheight]{%
        \node[anchor=#1,inner sep=0pt]
        at ($(current page.south west)+(#2,#3)$) {#4};
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\title{some title}
\date{01.01.2010}
\subtitle{some subtitle}
\author{some authors}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\placetextbox[south]{0.5}{0}{\includemedia[
    width=\paperwidth,
    height=\paperheight,
    keepaspectratio,
    activate=pageopen,
    passcontext,  %show VPlayer's right-click menu
    addresource=damm.mp4,
    flashvars={
        source=damm.mp4&autoPlay=true
    }
    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}}
\end{frame}
```